# Virtualbox is not running on CentOS 7

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, centos7

I have installed virtualbox 4.3 (also version 5.x). There is no problem in installation. But When I run it via terminal. It gives following warning

```
WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module
         available for the current kernel (3.10.0-229.11.1.el7.x86_64) or it failed to
         load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by

           sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup

         You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
```

When virtual machine starts and I select a VM, It gives following error.

```
Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is either not loaded or there is a permission problem with /dev/vboxdrv. Please reinstall the kernel module by executing

'/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup'

as root. If it is available in your distribution, you should install the DKMS package first. This package keeps track of Linux kernel changes and recompiles the vboxdrv kernel module if necessary.
```

When I run follwoing commad

```
sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```

This error appears

```
Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules                         [  OK  ]
Uninstalling old VirtualBox DKMS kernel modulesError! There are no instances of module: vboxhost
4.3.30 located in the DKMS tree.
Error! There are no instances of module: vboxhost
4.3.30 located in the DKMS tree.
Error! There are no instances of module: vboxhost
4.3.30 located in the DKMS tree.
Error! There are no instances of module: vboxhost
4.3.30 located in the DKMS tree.
                                                           [  OK  ]
Trying to register the VirtualBox kernel modules using DKMS[  OK  ]
Starting VirtualBox kernel modules                         [FAILED]
  (modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why)
```

And according to above guide, I run `dmesg` command and it shows following results at tail.

```
[   77.790816] tun: (C) 1999-2004 Max Krasnyansky <maxk@qualcomm.com>
[   77.826151] device virbr0-nic entered promiscuous mode
[   77.916096] virbr0: port 1(virbr0-nic) entered listening state
[   77.916105] virbr0: port 1(virbr0-nic) entered listening state
[   77.916153] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): virbr0: link is not ready
[   78.170824] virbr0: port 1(virbr0-nic) entered disabled state
[   96.372599] fuse init (API version 7.22)
[  116.798026] TCP: lp registered
[  840.569814] warning: `VirtualBox' uses 32-bit capabilities (legacy support in use)
```

What is the problem, I am tring to solve it for about two months but nothing solve my problem.
Please guide and answer to the point as I am not an expert in such things.

Comment: I've just posted the solution [without disabling Secure Boot here...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39030662/cant-install-virtualbox-in-arch/59536730#59536730)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, in BIOS setting, you should disable secure boots option is boot setting. It may solve your problem.