# Failed to update Virtualbox on ubuntu 15.10

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-15.10

I updated the version of Virtualbox from 5.0.4 to 5.1.9, but can not be used. The error message as follows:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zi3DI.png)

Proceed as follows:

```
$ uname -a
 Linux pc-name 4.2.0-42-generic #49-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 28 21:26:26 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

1). Run the following command to uninstall the old version

```
sudo apt-get remove virtualbox - \ * && sudo apt-get purge virtualbox - \ * && sudo rm ~ / "VirtualBox VMs" -Rf && sudo rm ~ / .config / VirtualBox / -Rf
```

There are the following major errors in the run:

```
Dpkg: Warning: The directory /usr/share/virtualbox is not empty when the virtualbox is uninstalled, so the directory is not deleted
```

2). Install the new version from the source (using the source provided by virtualbox.org)

```
sudo apt-get install -f virtualbox-5.1
```

There are the following major errors in the run:

```
Unknown media type in type 'all / all'
Unknown media type in type 'all / allfiles'
```

and

```
Vboxdrv.sh: failed: modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why.
There were problems setting up VirtualBox. To re-start the set-up process, run
/sbin/vboxconfig
As root.
```

3). I use dmesg view to get the following information:

```
    [26211.111276] PPP MPPE Compression module registered
    [31955.864023] Request for unknown module key 'virtualbox: b2b55b754f3bb6a535be36ff514e9e174b01bfda' err -11
    [31958.462125] Request for unknown module key 'virtualbox: b2b55b754f3bb6a535be36ff514e9e174b01bfda' err -11
    [32012.883861] capability: warning: `VirtualBox 'uses 32-bit capabilities (legacy support in use)
    [32155.086381] Request for unknown module key 'virtualbox: b2b55b754f3bb6a535be36ff514e9e174b01bfda' err -11
    [32397.551309] Request for unknown module key 'virtualbox: b2b55b754f3bb6a535be36ff514e9e174b01bfda' err -11
    [33462.912350] Request for unknown module key 'virtualbox: b2b55b754f3bb6a535be36ff514e9e174b01bfda' err -11
    [34179.544392] Request for unknown module key 'virtualbox: b2b55b754f3bb6a535be36ff514e9e174b01bfda' err -11
    [34277.077660] Request for unknown module key 'virtualbox: b2b55b754f3bb6a535be36ff514e9e174b01bfda' err -11
    [34281.740848] Request for unknown module key 'virtualbox: b2b55b754f3bb6a535be36ff514e9e174b01bfda' err -11
```

4). Then I ran again:

```
sudo dmesg --clear
sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
```

5). Suggest the following error

```
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
vboxdrv.sh: failed: modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why.

There were problems setting up VirtualBox. To re-start the set-up process, run
  /sbin/vboxconfig
As root.
```

6). Use dmesg view, did not get any information. 7). Find these solutions:      8). Use the following command

```
sudo /usr/lib/virtualbox/vboxdrv.sh setup
```

Suggesting that the following errors:

```
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
vboxdrv.sh: failed: modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why.
```

9). dmesg does not get any information 10). Use

```
dpkg -l | grep virtualbox
```

The following information is obtained

```
ii virtualbox-5.1 5.1.6-110634 ~ Ubuntu ~ wily amd64 Oracle VM VirtualBox
```

11). Use

```
sudo/sbin/vboxconfig
```

The following information is obtained

```
 vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
 vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
 vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
 vboxdrv.sh: failed: modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why.

 There were problems setting up VirtualBox. To re-start the set-up process, run
  /sbin/vboxconfig
 As root.
```

12) Here, do not know how to deal with. Please help me, very grateful!

Comment: I've just posted the solution [without disabling Secure Boot here...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39030662/cant-install-virtualbox-in-arch/59536730#59536730)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if Secure Boot is Enabled in your BIOS. If so, disable it. These are for 16.04 (it worked for me in 14.04):

https://askubuntu.com/questions/762136/cannot-reinstall-virtualbox-on-ubuntu-16-04

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/282265/starting-virtualbox-kernel-modules-failed